# How can I use BigInt class in vb.net? (visual studio 2008)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, bigint

recently i use int64.

but it's no more handle my data.

so  I want something like BigInt.

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use .NET 4.0 beta 1, you could use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx). Otherwise there are [various open source](http://github.com/ironruby/ironruby/blob/master/Merlin/Main/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Math/BigInteger.cs) libraries around.

Answer (score 1):

Use the J# BigInteger class as described here: [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [BigInt unsigned integer math library](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=403&lngWId=10)?

Answer (score 0):

your int64: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (9.2...E+18 †) (signed)

Try using Double: 4.94065645841246544E-324 through 1.79769313486231570E+308 † for positive values